# How can "from datetime import datetime" have different effects in two different files?

Tags: python

I have two identical import statements in two different files, but somehow one is importing the module while the other is importing the class. Does anyone know how this could be possible? First file is `v1/user/views.py` and the other one is `v1/meeting/views.py`.

[image]

[image]

Comment: A few things to check: do you have a `datetime.py` file in either directory? And if you delete each  *prior* `import` in turn, does the behavior change?

Comment: I would bet on your first suggestion @ASGM

Comment: @ASGM Thanks for the idea. Your second suggestion turned out to be correct. I'll write up the result.

Comment: Please post text not images. You may be on a zillion meter screen but I can't read a thing on my notebook.

Answer (score 1):

The *simplest* reason this could be possible is if you have a file called `datetime.py` in one of your directories, and the `import` statement is pulling from that.

Answer (score 0):

Found out thanks to @ASGM. Turns out I was importing a file called `serializers.py` that is using `import datetime`. This somehow messes up the definition of datetime.

[image]

[image]

[image]